# Detecting key release in a Bash script in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnome-terminal

I'm not really sure how to be more specific; I am looking for a way to capture input from the keyboard within a Bash script.

I am aware of some methods that involves detecting keys that are pressed, but I am interested in detecting keys that are released. Is their a way to do this from within a Bash script? Preferably with pure a Bash script, and not third-party Bash utilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
read -N 1
```

to get single keystrokes on bash.

Comment: can this also be used to detect when the key is released?

Comment: No - there is no portable way to do this.